# bash how to work with hours of the current time

Tags: bash, time

I can put commands to `.bash_profile` to run when user logins to the system. I want to disallow logining at certain hours. The algorithm:

```
if((HOUR(now) == 13) || (HOUR(now) < 7))
    exit
```

I know, how to do something like this in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    time_t rawtime; time (&rawtime);
    struct tm *tm_struct = localtime(&rawtime);

    int hour = tm_struct->tm_hour;

    if((hour == 13) || (hour < 7))
    {
        printf("hi\n");//exit will be used instead
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But I don't know, how to implement it in bash.

Comment: Users could always login using a different shell, which would bypass any check you put in `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Perhaps this would be helpful? http://askubuntu.com/questions/68918/how-do-i-restrict-my-kids-computing-time

Comment: The proper place to implement this kind of policy would be `pam.d`. Go to http://serverfault.com/ and search for a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `date` command to return just the hour:

```
hour=$(date +%H)
if (( hour == 13 || hour < 7 )); then
    exit
fi
```

Comment: Thanks; I started with `[[ ... ]]` and didn't change the operator after moving to `((...))`.

Answer (score 6):

Have to be careful with `date +%H` -- when that returns "08" or "09", and then you try to use that in an arithmetic expression, you'll get invalid octal errors:

```
$ hour="09"
$ if (( hour == 13 || hour < 7 )); then echo y; else echo n; fi
bash: ((: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
n
```

You can explicitly tell bash that your numbers are base 10:

```
$ if (( 10#$hour == 13 || 10#$hour < 7 )); then echo y; else echo n; fi
n
```

Or, use a different date format specifier: my date man page says `%k` and `%_H` return space-padded hour ( 0..23)

```
hour=$(date +%_H)
if (( hour == 13 || hour < 7 )); then ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
HOUR=`date +%H`
if [ $HOUR -eq 13 -o $HOUR -lt 7 ];then
    exit
fi
```

Note that unlike `()` the `[]` does not interpret `09` as octal number

Comment: It does work for 09. Check this:`if [ 09 -lt 7 ];then echo fail;fi` - does not print 'fail'

Comment: Wow! What a surprise for me. Yeah, 09 will throw errors in ``(( ))`` and in ``[[ ]]``, but not in ``[ ]``. Sorry. Can you edit your answer a little bit so I can remove my downvote? :)